# Streams of multibyte characters (non ascii) in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm thinking how to work with streams, just for the sake of it, and reading the MDN articles on it.

For example here there is parsing utf8 encoded text by lines in stream way [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamDefaultReader/read) where I am passing a cross-request-allowed URL for chinese-proverbs

```js
async function* makeTextFileLineIterator(fileURL) {
  const utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
  let response = await fetch(fileURL);
  let reader = response.body.getReader();
  let { value: chunk, done: readerDone } = await reader.read();
  chunk = chunk ? utf8Decoder.decode(chunk, { stream: true }) : "";

  let re = /\r\n|\n|\r/gm;
  let startIndex = 0;

  for (;;) {
    let result = re.exec(chunk);
    if (!result) {
      if (readerDone) {
        break;
      }
      let remainder = chunk.substr(startIndex);
      ({ value: chunk, done: readerDone } = await reader.read());
      chunk =
        remainder + (chunk ? utf8Decoder.decode(chunk, { stream: true }) : "");
      startIndex = re.lastIndex = 0;
      continue;
    }
    yield chunk.substring(startIndex, result.index);
    startIndex = re.lastIndex;
  }
  if (startIndex < chunk.length) {
    // last line didn't end in a newline char
    yield chunk.substr(startIndex);
  }
}

async function run(){
for await (let line of makeTextFileLineIterator("https://chinese-proverbs.onrender.com/api/proverbs?page=1&limit=100")) {
  console.log(line);
 }
}

run()
```

And unexpectedly to me, the parsing seems correct.

### Question

What happens here for non ascii characters? So, taking these main lines:

```
async function* makeTextFileLineIterator(fileURL) {
  const utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
  let response = await fetch(fileURL);
  let reader = response.body.getReader();
  let { value: chunk, done: readerDone } = await reader.read();
  chunk = chunk ? utf8Decoder.decode(chunk, { stream: true }) : "";
  ...
```

If the stream chunk ends in the first byte of a multi-byte character such as `11101101 10010101 10011100`, will this code or the decoder handle this chunks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the stream chunk ends in the first byte of a multi-byte character [...], will this code or the decoder handle this chunks ?

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder), the default behavior of `TextDecoder` is:

> decoder will substitute malformed data with a replacement character

[Replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) is this thing: `�` found at code point `U+FFFD`.

So if your last chunk is truncated, decoder will recognize the error and finish the string with `�`:

```js
// "αβγ" but the last character is truncated
let bytes = new Uint8Array([0xce, 0xb1, 0xce, 0xb2, 0xce]);
console.log(new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(bytes));
```

But if the sequence of bytes that encode one character is split between chunks, decoder will consider that and correctly restore the character on the next iteration:

```js
// Beta in "αβγ" is split between chunks
let bytes = [
    new Uint8Array([0xce, 0xb1, 0xce]),
    new Uint8Array([0xb2, 0xce, 0xb3])
];
let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
console.log(
    decoder.decode(bytes[0], { stream: true }), '+',
    decoder.decode(bytes[1])
);
```

---

Under the spoiler is a snippet to experiment a little bit.
Erase the last byte `8e` which is used by emoji, and you'll see how decoder generates replacement character.
By the way, `String` is also [editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable).

```js
let elemUTF8 = document.getElementById('utf-8');
let elemString = document.getElementById('string');
let elemCodepoints = document.getElementById('codepoints');

let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
let encoder = new TextEncoder();

function updateString () {
    let hex = elemUTF8.value.replace(/[^\da-f]/ig, '');
    let bytes = new Uint8Array(hex.length >>> 1);
    for (let i = 0; i < hex.length - 1; i += 2) {
        bytes[i >>> 1] = parseInt(hex.slice(i, i + 2), 16);
    }
    elemString.innerText = decoder.decode(bytes);
}

function updateUTF8 () {
    let bytes = encoder.encode(elemString.innerText);
    let hex = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        hex.push(bytes[i].toString(16).padStart(2, '0'));
    }
    elemUTF8.value = hex.join(' ');
}

function updateCodepoints () {
    let string = elemString.innerText;
    let codepoints = [];
    for (let codepoint of string) {
        codepoints.push(codepoint.codePointAt(0).toString(16));
    }
    elemCodepoints.innerText = codepoints.join(', ');
}

elemUTF8.addEventListener('input', () => {
    updateString();
    updateCodepoints();
});

elemString.addEventListener('input', () => {
    updateUTF8();
    updateCodepoints();
});

updateUTF8();
updateCodepoints();
```

```css
* { font: 14px monospace; }
div { margin-top: 6px; }
```

```html
<div>UTF-8 bytes:</div>
<div><textarea id="utf-8" cols="60"></textarea></div>
<div>String: &quot;<span id="string" contenteditable="true">Yo dawg </span>&quot;</div>
<div>Code points: <span id="codepoints"></span></div>
```

Comment: Impressive, so the decoder has a sort of memory, I guess it is found in the `decoder` object. And so basically you dont have to worry about truncated characters, if they are completed afterwards, only about "corrupted characters".

Comment: @Minsky, "so the decoder has a sort of memory" – Yes, and it is a very practical feature actually. For example, fetching things from the net can be relatively slow, but the received parts can be decoded and processed right away without having to wait while the loading is complete.